# Customise info order and punctuation with biblatex-apa and unpublished thesis

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

According to an APA manual I have, in the references section, an unpublished dissertation should be formatted like this:

> Doe, J. (2015). *Title* (Unpublished doctoral dissertation). Some university, City.

With `biblatex-apa`, the closest thing I can get is using the following example code:

**main.tex:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[english=american,autostyle=false]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah \parencite{doe2015}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**bibliography.bib:**

```
@Unpublished{doe2015a,
  Title                    = {Title},
  Author                   = {Doe, J.},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Location                 = {City},
  School                   = {Some University},
  Note                     = {(Unpublished doctoral dissertaion)}
}
```

However, the result is still not exactly what I want. The order and the use of punctuation are different:

> Doe, J. (2015). *Title*, Some University. (Unpublished doctoral dissertaion), City.

How can I customise it to match the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theses and dissertations should use the `thesis` (or the `phdthesis` and `mastersthesis` aliases)  type, not the `unpublished` type.  So this is part of the problem.

But `biblatex-apa` still doesn't format this exactly as your format shows (I would usually defer to `biblatex-apa`, since it is quite accurate as far as I know.)  But if you want to change this, you can change the way the `type+institution` is formatted:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[english=british,autostyle=false]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\renewbibmacro*{type+institution}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{type}\AND\iffieldundef{institution}}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iflistundef{institution}
         {\setunit*{\addspace}}
         {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
       \printfield{type}}%
       \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
       \printlist{institution}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printlist{location}%
     \newunit}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{doe2015a,
  Title = {Title},
  Author = {Doe, J.},
  Year = {2015},
  Location = {City},
  School = {Some University},
  Type = {unpublished doctoral dissertation}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah \parencite{doe2015a}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Note` field to `Howpublished`. To suppress punctuation between title and ‘unpublished …’, a small patch will do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[english=american,autostyle=false]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{unpublished}{%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
}{}{}

    \usepackage{filecontents}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
   \begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@Unpublished{doe2015a,
  Title = {Title},
  Author = {Doe, J.},
  Year = {2015},
  Location = {City},
  School = {Some University},
  Howpublished = {(Unpublished doctoral dissertation)}
}
    \end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah \parencite{doe2015a}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]